# time.mktime time.strptime returns negative number

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

This code:

```
print(time.mktime(time.strptime("Jan 10 13:44:31", "%b %d %H:%M:%S")))
```

Returns:

```
-2208136529.0
```

Why am I getting a negative number?

Thanks for your help.

Steve

Comment: `>>> time.strptime("Jan 10 13:44:31", "%b %d %H:%M:%S")
time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=13, tm_min=44, tm_sec=31, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=10, tm_isdst=-1)` . Maybe a hint here: `tm_year=1900`

Comment: So, if there's not Year in the input string, it defaults to 1900?  I guess that makes sense, it has to have something in that field.  Not sure how I'm going to handle this but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the year to 1970 solved my issue. I used the below code to change the year:

```
datetime.replace(year=1970)
```